# error al crear relaciones en mysql

Tags: mysql

al actualizar el dato id_estado en la tabla tb_extintores se actualizan todos los datos en la columna id estado de tb_registro_bloqueo_extintor

solo deberia actualizarce el id_estado de un solo codigo no de todos.

no se si la relacion esta mal creada

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    tb_extintores   CREATE TABLE `tb_extintores` (
     `id_extintor` int(30) NOT NULL,
     `rut_cliente` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
     `fecha_recarga` date DEFAULT NULL,
     `fecha_vencimiento` date DEFAULT NULL,
     `id_kilo` int(10) NOT NULL,
     `id_tipo` int(10) NOT NULL,
     `id_estado` int(10) NOT NULL,
     `id_asignado` int(10) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (`id_extintor`),
     KEY `id_estado` (`id_estado`),
     KEY `id_tipo` (`id_tipo`),
     KEY `id_kilo` (`id_kilo`),
     KEY `rut_cliente` (`rut_cliente`),
     KEY `rut_cliente_2` (`rut_cliente`),
     KEY `rut_cliente_3` (`rut_cliente`),
     KEY `id_asignado` (`id_asignado`),
     CONSTRAINT `tb_extintores_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`id_estado`) REFERENCES `tb_estado` (`id_estado`) ON DELETE NO ACTION,
     CONSTRAINT `tb_extintores_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_tipo`) REFERENCES `tb_tipo_extintor` (`id_tipo`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE,
     CONSTRAINT `tb_extintores_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`id_kilo`) REFERENCES `tb_kilos_extintor` (`id_kilo`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE,
     CONSTRAINT `tb_extintores_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`id_asignado`) REFERENCES `tb_extintor_asignado` (`id_asignado`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1



tb_registro_bloqueo_extintor    CREATE TABLE `tb_registro_bloqueo_extintor` (
 `codigo` int(30) NOT NULL,
 `id_motivo` int(10) NOT NULL,
 `id_estado` int(10) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`codigo`),
 KEY `id_motivo` (`id_motivo`),
 KEY `id_estado` (`id_estado`),
 KEY `codigo` (`codigo`),
 KEY `id_estado_2` (`id_estado`),
 CONSTRAINT `tb_registro_bloqueo_extintor_ibfk_2` FOREIGN KEY (`id_motivo`) REFERENCES `tb_motivo_bloqueo_extintor` (`id_motivo`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `tb_registro_bloqueo_extintor_ibfk_3` FOREIGN KEY (`codigo`) REFERENCES `tb_extintores` (`id_extintor`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE,
 CONSTRAINT `tb_registro_bloqueo_extintor_ibfk_4` FOREIGN KEY (`id_estado`) REFERENCES `tb_extintores` (`id_estado`) ON DELETE NO ACTION ON UPDATE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: En vez de tantas imágenes, que sirven de casi nada, sería mejor que compartas el texto del resultado de esta consulta: `SHOW CREATE TABLE mitabla;` cambiando `mitabla` por cada una de las tablas implicadas. Así podremos ver cómo se relacionan las tablas.

Comment: como estas haciendo el update el error puede estar hay ?

Comment: al actualizar el id_estado de la tabla tb_extintores automaticamente deberia actualizarse el id_estado de la tabla tb_registro_bloqueo_extintor correspondiente al mismo codigo pero se actualizan todos los datos de id_estado

Comment: UPDATE tb_extintores SET id_estado = '2' WHERE tb_extintores.id_extintor = 1;

Comment: @sebastianbizamainostroza honestamente no se mucho sobre `MySQL`, pero ¿por qué usas `ON UPDATE CASCADE` en la `tb_registro_bloqueo_extintor_ibfk_4`? Mira esta [respuesta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1481524/4092887) puede que el problema esté allí.

Comment: para que se actualice cuando se cambia el estado en la tabla tb_extintores. tengo otra tabla donde se realiza lo mismo y hay si funciona en esta solo da ese problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

debes establecer en primer lugar el parámetro a actualizar id_estado = 2 que es el cambio que quieres realizar, al referirme a barrido de tabla me refiero a que si no delimitas con where tb_extintores.id_extintor =1, entonces lo que harás es que a todos los campos de la tabla tb_extintores les establecerás id_estado = 2, así o quieres una mejor explicación?

```
UPDATE tb_extintores SET id_estado = 2 WHERE tb_extintores.id_extintor = 1;
```

Comment: Hola Rafael. tu respuesta podría ser válida, pero ha sido marcada como de baja calidad. ¿Podrías extenderla? Intenta explicar por qué  tu respuesta solucionaría el problema o las ventajas de hacerlo de esta manera. Échale un vistazo a [answer] si tienes dudas.

Comment: en parte ese era mi error al crear las relaciones no delimitaba un criterio en el update en cascada por esa razon me actualizaba todos los datos.

Comment: No se porque ha sido marcada como respuesta de baja calidad si es la query correcta y apropiada para solventar el problema, pero si quieres una explicación extendida con gusto